# ontology on the semantic web, database on syntactic web

Tags: semantics, semantic-web

can anyone tell me what commonalities and diffrences are between an ontology on the semantic web and a database on the syntactic web?

Comment: (+1) I'm not sure why someone downvoted you.  But, this is a good question for answers.semanticweb.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By going to answers.semanticweb.com you could likely get a thoughtful and descriptive comparison of the two.  Since I'm short on time I'll just give you the resources where you can dig in further. See Wikipedia for [Syntactic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_web) and for [Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web).  See also:

- [Executive’s Quick Start Guide to Web 3.0 and the Semantic Web](http://www.metadataaustralia2010.com/pdf/Mills%20Quickstart%20Guide.pdf)
- [Linked Data: The Story so Far](http://tomheath.com/papers/bizer-heath-berners-lee-ijswis-linked-data.pdf)
- [RDF Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax/)
- [RDFa Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/)